# excel delete rows in some cases

Tags: vba, excel, delete-row

How can I delete the whole row of an Excel sheet, if in the column G has a number that starts with 210.

I don't want to delete the row if the cell has 210 somewhere inside, but only when start with it.

Comment: It can't be done by using formulas - I mean delete, only find out such rows. Is VBA an option for you?

Comment: I don't know it but tell me what to search for if you can

Comment: are the numbers stored as numbers or text? (i.e. by default, are they displayed left- or right-aligned?)

Answer (score 3):

Use this code:

```
Sub RemoveRows()

Dim i As Long

i = 1

Do While i <= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    If Left(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G" & i).Formula, 3) = "210" Then
        ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp2cwphhhdn3l98/RemoweRows210.xlsm

To see it and run, press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>, open Module1 and press <kbd>F5</kbd>. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to do it without code but purely in the UI, this is how you could do this pretty efficiently:

1. Insert a temporary column (e.g. right of column G) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> in any cell in column H, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>)
2. Fill the column with the formula `=LEFT(TEXT(G1),3)="210"` - this will return `TRUE` for all rows you look for
3. Apply an AutoFilter to either that new column or the full range (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>)
4. Filter that column for `TRUE` - this way, only the rows you wish to delete remain
5. Select all rows and delete (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> in any cell in the table, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>)
6. Delete the temporary column (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Space</kbd> in any cell in column H, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>)

Done!